# include CDataColumn - how to properly use require_once with yii

Tags: php, yii

I am attempting to use the yii extension DataColumn in my CGridView. However, I am either running into an error of where I am using require_once incorrectly or I am misusing the DataColumn as a whole.

For reference this is how I am including DataColumn.php which is located in the components folder under protected in yii.

```
require_once(Yii::app()->basePath . '/components/DataColumn.php');
```

Data Column looks like this

```
 class DataColumn extends CDataColumn
{
    /**
     * @var boolean whether the htmlOptions values should be evaluated. 
     */
    public $evaluateHtmlOptions = false;

     /*
    ...
```

However, with this include and this DataColumn I am running into the error

```
include(CDataColumn.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Which seems strange - is this because the class that is being extended doesn't exist? Or should I rename DataColumn? Am I perhaps calling DataColumn incorrectly?

**_________________________** *Edit

I am calling the gridview like this

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'account-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'name',
        'mobile_comp',
        'msisdn',
        // this formats the balance
        array(
            'class'=>'DataColumn'
            'header'=>'Balance (Rwf)',
            'name'=>'balance',
            'evaluateHtmlOptions'=>true,
            'htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'balance'),
            'value'=>function($data){
            return number_format($data->balance);
            },

        ), 
        /*
        'company',
        */ 

        array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{manage}',
        'buttons'=>array
        (
        'manage' => array
        (
            'label'=>'Manage',
            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("account/view", array("id"=>$data->id))'
         ),
        ),
    ),
))); 
 ?>
```

Comment: How are you calling DataColumn in your Grid View?

Comment: I'm calling it like so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to include `DataColumn` separately. Since you have put it in Components folder, Yii automatically imports it. [See Import documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#import-detail), However you do need to reference the full class path alias while adding the new column to the GridView like this

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CGridView',array(
  ....
  ....
  'columns'=>array(
    array(
     class'=>'application.components.DataColumn'
      ...
    )
  );
```

Comment: to clarify, when you do something like 'application.components.Datacolumn' - this already assumes you are in protected? or how does it know the right path from here?

Comment: As you know yii 1.x does not use namespaces, therefore aliases are used using the "dot syntax" application(i.e. protected directory) is one root aliases along with webroot(where index.php is present), ext(extensions), system(framework), etc see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace for full info

Comment: Thans Manquer! What do you mean by name spaces in this context though?

Comment: i meant namespaces in the usual context only, Yii(i.e. php) should know clearly which class(file) to call when you are referencing `DataColumn`, in Yii 2.x everything is namespaced so you will have an use statement like `use app\components\DataColumn;`, and refer the class normally,since in Yii 1.x you cannot do that you have to use aliases

Comment: To expand Yii 1.x was designed to be used without namespaces to provide support to lower versions of PHP, Now since most hosts/distributions are atleast on 5.4/5 (Yii 2.x requires >= 5.4), Yii implements  the OOP features of PHP that were released relatively recently